# Binary search tree rotation

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

I want to create an algorithm to sort binary search trees to make them balanced. But I can't do that If I don't understand myself how each step works!

So I have a binary search tree that I want to rotate to make it balanced. I already have and know the answer as shown by figure 2, but am unsure of the steps necessary to get to that point

Figure 1:
[image]

Figure 2:
[image]

Any pointers would be great.

Also I am using http://visualgo.net/bst.html

Comment: I think this question is way too broad. There are at least dozens of books that explain this, notably google "CLRS Introduction to Algorithms". Study one of them, and if you have a more specific question, ask it later.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you need here is called [tree rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_rotation)

What you have done from step 1 to step 2 is a left rotation for node **16** like this:

[image]

Node **16** is imbalanced and size(left child) < size(right child) =>

1. We need to transfer the **16** node to left child,
2. Get a new node (the **smallest**) from the right child as the new node (**18**  since is the smallest)
3. Rebalance the right child

Comment: Thanks mate! Copy-paste FTW.